# An if statement in a C++ for loop to decrement by alternating amounts

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm not sure why but the program stops decrementing at Number = -12.75. The program should run until the Number = -50.0.

```
#include <iostream>

// create variables to be used in the loops
float Number = 50.0; // starting Number
int Counter1 = 0; // counter for .25 decrements
int Counter2 = 0; // counter for 1 decrements

std::cout << '\n' << Number << '\n';
// loop to decrement Number down from 50.0 to -50.0
for (int i = 50; i >= -50; --i)
{
    // if statement to determine which loop to use
    if ((Counter1 + Counter2) % 2 == 0)
    {
        Number = Number - 0.25;
        std::cout << Number << '\n';
        ++Counter1;
    }
    else
    {
        Number = Number - 1.0;
        std::cout << Number << '\n';
        ++Counter2;
    }
} 
   int TotalCounter = Counter1 + Counter2;
   std::cout << "\nCombined trips through loops: " << TotalCounter << '\n';
```

Comment: Why do you expect `Number` to go to -50? The result of -12.75 looks correct.

Comment: You probably want to reread your code carefully. Your loop runs 100 times, and every 2nd time it minuses 1

Comment: You are checking if `i>=-50`, not `Number`. If you want the loop to run until `Number` is -50, just modify the condition

Comment: @Tas yes that is correct. I used the total of the counters so that when they are 0 or even it subtracts -.25 or -1 when odd.

Comment: @cigien the goal is to get to -50

Comment: @BenAlterman You have `51` even numbers and `50` odd numbers between `[-50, 50]`, so what you calculate now is `50 - (51 * 0.25 + 50 * 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to stop when `Number` reaches -50, then you should modify the condition at which the for-loop should stop. This should work:

```
#include <iostream>

// create variables to be used in the loops
float Number = 50.0; // starting Number
int Counter1 = 0; // counter for .25 decrements
int Counter2 = 0; // counter for 1 decrements

std::cout << '\n' << Number << '\n';
// loop to decrement Number down from 50.0 to -50.0
for (int i = 50; Number >= -50; --i)
{
    // if statement to determine which loop to use
    if ((Counter1 + Counter2) % 2 == 0)
    {
        Number = Number - 0.25;
        std::cout << Number << '\n';
        ++Counter1;
    }
    else
    {
        Number = Number - 1.0;
        std::cout << Number << '\n';
        ++Counter2;
    }
} 
   int TotalCounter = Counter1 + Counter2;
   std::cout << "\nCombined trips through loops: " << TotalCounter << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting the correct result you have to change the for loop condition that you have used i<=-50.Use while loop instead as : " while(Number>-50) " Because it takes more iterations to reach Number to -50 then 101 iterations you are giving in for loop.
hope u got this.